# How to add images one by one as I scroll

Tags: ios

I have an requirement where I had to load multiple images and videos in the ScrollView
but on iPad 2 my application crashes when I load entire set on one go.It says that application
exits due to heavy memory pressure.

I would like to know how to handle this issue and it it possible to load images one by one when i scroll? and if yes then how it can be done

Comment: Greetings. As it would be helpful if you show what you have tried on this front. We are always willing to help but do not want to write your code for you

Comment: By your question i have a sneaking suspicion that you have set the content of scroll view by multiplying it with number of images and loaded all the images in for loop in one go.

Comment: I think you should use UICollectionView, but i don't sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think The Best will be to  use UITableView instead of scrollView. As tableview uses DEQUEUE so it will do the part of loading/unloading the visible portion of tableview. Table view cell can be customized any way You want.

Hope it will help.

Answer (score -1):

Paging is the way to go.

If you load all the images in the memory then you are compromising scalability in big way for one or two image it will be fine for large number say hundreds it will crash.

One approach is you keep only three images in memory previous image----current image being displayed and ------next image ready for display. And you have to use lazy loading and image caching

Following links will help you

.[Icarousel](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/icarousel) 
.[AFnetworking's uiimageview category for lazy loading and caching](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking)
.[ASImageView a light weight uiimageview category](https://github.com/Amar11s/ASImageView) if you dont want to integrate full AFNetworking in your project